# Accessing Twitter API post authentication via Auth0

Tags: twitter, access-token, auth0

I have successfully obtained the access_token post Twitter Authentication via Auth0. I am trying to use that access_token in the header but am getting a 401 error from Twitter.

```
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('twitter_access_token');        

  $http.jsonp('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
```

What am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Auth0's own access token. You'll have to get a Twitter access token first as described here => https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/calling-an-external-idp-api